# If statement not working showing correct results in foreach array

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, foreach

I created a `foreach` loop with a `if..else` statement which should check whether a variable is null/empty or not. Everything seems to work fine. However, the results returned all have one outcome despite some variables being empty and some other not.

I tried using different bits within the `if..else` statement such as

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($password))
```

or

```
if ($password -eq $null)
```

or

```
if ($password.length -gt 2)
```

but I had no luck whatsoever.

I started working on this to find quickly which computers didn't have LAPS working to investigate why. The issue is fixed but this script is still bugging me as I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is my code, tried to use both the `ms-mcs-admpwd` attribute and the LAPS built-in `get-admpwd`, no difference.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties * |
             Select-Object Name, ms-mcs-admpwd

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $password = Get-ADComputer $computer.Name -Properties * |
                Select ms-mcs-admpwd

    if ($password) {
        Write-Host "LAPS password on $computer present"
    } else {
        Write-Host "LAPS password on $computer not present"
    }

    Write-Host $password
    Write-Host " "
}
```

This is the outcome:

```
LAPS password on @{Name=Computer1; ms-mcs-admpwd=} present
@{ms-mcs-admpwd=}
LAPS password on @{Name=Computer2; ms-mcs-admpwd=8CG1]8,q.j} present
@{ms-mcs-admpwd=8CG1]8,q.j}
LAPS password on @{Name=Computer3; ms-mcs-admpwd=P2v94d+05q} present
@{ms-mcs-admpwd=P2v94d+05q}
LAPS password on @{Name=Computer4; ms-mcs-admpwd=} present
@{ms-mcs-admpwd=}
```

As you can see Computer1 and Computer4 have no `ms-mcs-admpwd` attribute, yet the outcome is the same as Computer2 and Computer3.

Comment: The object in the variable `$computer` already has the `ms-mcs-admpwd` attribute, so there's no need to do *another* AD query for each computer. Use `$password = $computer.'ms-mcs-admpwd'` or `$password = $computer | Select-Object -Expand ms-mcs-admpwd` to assign just the value of that attribute to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ADComputer $computer.name -Properties * | Select ms-mcs-admpwd
```

is returning an object not the string that I think you're looking for.
You need `$password.'ms-mcs-admpwd'`

```
If($password.'ms-mcs-admpwd')
    {write-host "LAPS password on $computer present"}

Else {Write-host "LAPS password on $computer not present"}

Write-host $password.'ms-mcs-admpwd'
```

Comment: It makes sense - thanks for the explanation Justin!

Comment: Note that for dot-access to work you MUST put the property name in quotes if it contains hyphens or other special characters: `$password.'ms-mcs-admpwd'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the $password variable is not null, empty, or false so it will always be evaluated as true. For the code as written you'll want to change the evaluation to:

```
If($password.'ms-mcs-admpwd')
{write-host "LAPS password on $computer present"}
```

In addition running `Get-ADComputer` twice is unneeded since the $computers variable already has the information you need.